# How use requireJs with vertx?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, vert.x

For a project, I have to use vertx for a web app. So in my main.js I need to require a file of vertx. If I don't use requirejs, it doesn't work on firefox, and when I use it, the vertx's file requires others vertx's files which require others...  So I don't find how can I do to make it work, because the require in the vertx's files aren't recognized by requireJs.

To compile and lanch my project I use maven (I have the depencies needed to vertx in).

app.js :

```
// For any third party dependencies, like jQuery, place them in the lib 
folder.

// Configure loading modules from the lib directory,
// except for 'app' ones, which are in a sibling
// directory.
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'lib',
    paths: {
        app: '../app'
    }
});

// Start loading the main app file. Put all of
// your application logic in there.
requirejs(['app/main']);
```

main.js :

```
define(function(require){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var WebClient = require('vertx-web-client-js/web_client');
        var client = WebClient.create(vertx);
    });
});
```

Thanks for help :D

Answer (score 1):

`RequireJS` requires a different module loader from the one shipped with Vert.x (`commonjs`). However it can be done easily. For example, I wrote an implementation a while ago:

https://github.com/pmlopes/vertx3-nashorn.next/blob/master/nashorn/src/main/resources/amdlite.js

Assuming that you are just taking that loader and ignore the rest of the experiment, you can add it to your project by loading it in your main script as:

```
// load is a nashorn specific command
load('amdlite.js');
```

After that you can do:

```
define(['vertx', 'yourDepHere'], function (vertx, yourDepHere) {
  // then you can use it as in your example
});
```

To configure your module location the loader uses the following config:

```
define.amd.config({
  // paths is a list of paths
  paths = { ... },
  // baseUrl is the base for all modules
  baseUrl = '',
  // plugins is where you could register AMD plugins, e.g.: transpilers, etc...
  plugins = ...
});
```